# How to install dssp (secondary structure assignments) under 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, software-installation

I am trying to install dssp on ubuntu 12.04. I am new to ubuntu. I tried this

```
sudo apt-get install dssp
```

Please give suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

DSSP is not in official ubuntu repositories, but you can install it manually:

```
sudo wget ftp://ftp.cmbi.ru.nl/pub/software/dssp/dssp-2.0.4-linux-amd64 -O /usr/local/bin/dssp
```

or

```
sudo wget ftp://ftp.cmbi.ru.nl/pub/software/dssp/dssp-2.0.4-linux-i386 -O /usr/local/bin/dssp
```

And for the end:

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/dssp
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.When I typed "chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/dssp" I got the following error message "chmod: changing permissions of `/usr/local/bin/dssp': Operation not permitted" . Any suggestions for correcting this?

Comment: oh sorry.. i forgot about **sudo**. You must type `sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/dssp`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do you know how to compile dssp? I  can't see /usr/local/bin directory in my system.

Comment: If you really dont have /usr/local/bin directory, try `sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin`. If you wanna compiling dssp from source, you need download [this](ftp://ftp.cmbi.ru.nl/pub/software/dssp/dssp-2.0.4.tgz) and of course you need install `build-essential`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I created /usr/local/bin directory. After this I typed "sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/dssp" . But dssp is not in /usr/local/bin. So I tried to download dssp.tgz and extracted it. But I don't know how to execute it?

Comment: Read again my first answer. You must download dssp to /usr/local/bin, and then you can change chmod.

Comment: I downloaded dssp using your code.But same problem. I can't see dssp folder in /usr/local/bin.

Answer (score 1):

You can install DSSP in 12.04 with [ppa:sfleischmann/tcbsys](https://launchpad.net/~sfleischmann/+archive/tcbsys) repository.

Follow these steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sfleischmann/tcbsys

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install dssp
```