# Problem with executing dssp (secondary structure assignment)

Tags: software-center, executable, error-handling

I followed a previous post to install dssp on Ubuntu

[How to install dssp (secondary structure assignments) under 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137297/how-to-install-dssp-secondary-structure-assignments-under-12-04)

After the installation I tried to execute dssp which was in `/usr/local/bin/dssp`
But it gave me the following error
bash: `/usr/local/bin/dssp`: cannot execute binary file

Also I tried to analyses some trajectory files from a simulation using the code

```
do_dssp -s md.tpr -f traj.xtc
```

But it also failed giving me the error below

```
Reading file md.tpr, VERSION 4.5.5 (single precision)
Reading file md.tpr, VERSION 4.5.5 (single precision)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Please post me a solution for this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you did not write
 `sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/dssp` ?
(I just installed and used dssp, with the link that you provided, and it works OK)

(You should make another question for the other problem (with a better explanation and new title))

Answer (score 0):

This is bug. I was using do_dssp with previous versions of GROMACS. It did not run when it was upgraded to version 4.5.5. 
Somebody please upload GROMACS 4.6 in UBUNTU software center. I believe this issue had been fixed in GROMACS 4.6.
see [this](http://www.shocksolution.com/2012/10/getting-dssp-to-run-with-gromacs-4-5-5-on-red-hat-linux/) link.

Answer (score 0):

Just updating a little bit.
This is program is very easy to install in Ubuntu 14.04

```
fmp@lucy:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install dssp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
```

---

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
libboost-iostreams1.54.0 libboost-program-options1.54.0
libboost-system1.54.0 libboost-thread1.54.0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
dssp libboost-iostreams1.54.0 libboost-program-options1.54.0
libboost-system1.54.0 libboost-thread1.54.0
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Setting up dssp (2.2.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.3) ...
```

You have to call it with mkdssp!!
Examples:

To calculate the secondary structure for the file 1crn.pdb and
write the result to a file called 1crn.dssp, you type:

```
mkdssp -i 1crn.pdb -o 1crn.dssp
```